# java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException when Files.walk(rootPath).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(new Consumer<Path>());

Tags: java, nio, filesystemwatcher

I am writing a small app in java that concerns files in the file system and i use the packages of java.nio. to solve recursive deleting of a file tree: my code looks like:

```
                Files.walk(rootPath).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(new Consumer<Path>() 
            {
                @Override
                public void accept(Path path)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (Files.isDirectory(path))
                        {
                            unregister(path);
                        }
                        Files.delete(path);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

The file tree looks like this:

```
Level 1 folder
  Level 2 folder
    Level 3 folder
      Level 4 file
      Level 4 file
      Level 4 ... files
```

the code deletes all files in the last folder, then deletes the last folder. This folder does not disappear but remains until the program ends. So the app must lock this file.

Every directory is registered for for events from the file system (with path.register(watcher). Before the delete I remove this registering from the folder. Nevertheless the lock seems not to be removed.

Do you have any solution proposal to this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Christian

Comment: maybe you are better of using `Files.walkFileTree(start, options, maxDepth, visitor)` and implement the `postVisitDirectory` to delete the directory if it matches whatever condition. maybe that solves your problem

Comment: I've tried with your proposal, thank you! Nevertheless it does not work I regularly get  a filenotemptyexception when the folder on level 2 is deleted. the folder of level 3 seems to hold a lock, but I cannot find out, why. It must be the app, but I removed all possible references (i.e. watchkeys). Any other idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: a question, why do you delete recoursivly instead of just deleting the parent which also removes the childss?

Comment: A non empty directory can not be deleted, as I've read in the docs.

Comment: ah yeah that right. i just ran your code (removed the unregister part) and its working fine. i don't get any exception there. maybe the lock is from some other program like the explorer? you can open the "Resource Monitor" of windows, go to CPU tab and search for the file directory in "Associated Handles". this will show you which programs access the directory

Comment: Can you print the contents of the directory in your catch clause as soon as you get DirectoryNotEmptyException? Are there other processes actively creating new files in these directories?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Unfortunately I seem not to have the rights to see the recource monitor. I will try at home...
@ DodgyCodeException: I also will try that at home.
Thank you for your help. I will call back...

Comment: You could also simply shut down pretty much any program you can find to ensure they are not accessing the directory. Also note that a CMD which is in the working directory, blocks it